# TreeMap constructor of List values

Tags: java, list, constructor, treemap

I have a `Class1` with private attribute `TreeMap<Long, List<Class2>> tree;` and others, I want to write a constructor `Class1(Class1 copyOfClass1)`. Should I create the `List` values of the `TreeMap` explicitly (e.g., in a loop), or using `this.tree=new TreeMap(copyOfClass1.tree)` does that?

Comment: Do you want a deep copy or shallow copy?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `this.tree=new TreeMap(copyOfClass1.tree)` it will be equivalent as

```
this.tree=new TreeMap();
this.tree.putAll(copyOfClass1.tree)
```

However, it will not make a copy of the list that are stored in the map. The keys will be pointing to the same lists.

If you dont want this behavior I would suggest to iterate over the entries and to make a copy of the lists.

```
    this.tree = new TreeMap<Long, List<Class2>>();
    for (Entry<Long, List<Class2>> entry : copyOfClass1.tree.entrySet()) {
        this.tree.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<Class2>(entry.getValue()));
    }
```

Comment: And if instead of List I am using another class that I have created, do I need to do the same? I mean, only primitive types are copied by value?

Comment: Yes you need to do the same.

About the "copy by value":
"Java is always pass-by-value. The difficult thing can be to understand that Java passes objects as references passed by value."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference